# A question in Dynamical systems

Tags: dynamical-systems

Considering the discrete time logistic growth model,

$$N_{t+1} = \lambda N_t\left(1-\frac{N_t}{K}\right)$$

where $\lambda = 1+ b -d >0$ is the net reproductive rate and $K>0$ is a parameter that affects how the population grows when the population is large.

I have determined the two equilibrium points of this system which are,

$$N^*=0$$

$$N^* = K\left(1-\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)$$

found the conditions for each of the equilibria that I found above to be unstable.

Here is my explanation below,

$$f'(x) = \lambda -\frac{2x\lambda}{K}$$

Using $x=0$

$$f'(0) = \lambda$$

So it is unstable when $\lambda>1$

Using $x = K\left(1-\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)$ it is unstable when $\lambda >3, 0 < \lambda <1$

I believe I have done everything correct to this point.

**My question is how do I give the values of $N_0>0$, $K>0$ and $\lambda>0$ such that $N_1<0$, and how do I calculate $N_1$? Thanks!**

Answer (score 2):

Yes. All of your assumptions are correct. I checked it. But according to your problem if $N_0, K$ and $\lambda$ are positive, then from the first iteration $$N_1=\lambda N_0\left(1-\frac{N_0}{K}\right),$$ you always get $N_1$ as non negative since $N_0<K$ (the population is at most its carrying capacity).

But what is your actual motivation according to the problem? I think it may be positiveness of population in the model.

Comment: how did you calculate $N_1$?

Comment: but from the question isn't $N_1<0?$

Comment: @user123 You just put $t=0$ in the discrete time  logistic growth model and get $N_1$ as i mentioned in the answer (Here note that $t$ is non negative interger).

Comment: No. $N_1\nless0$ if $N_0,K$, $\lambda$ are positive and $N_t<K$ at all population level $t$ due to ecological significance.